re-heapify an array-(min)heap after modifying current minimum and a few other elements
I have a question similar to question-1 and question-2. Q-1 describes an approach for modifying a single element of array and re-sorting. Q-2 talks about deleting an element from a heap and re-heapifying by replacing the last element in the heap at the root and bubbling it down.
In the approach of Q-2, does deleting an element from a heap incur a memory-rearrangement cost? As in: in each outer iteration, I would have to re-allocate a heap from scratch, rather than use an existing one. Would there be a benefit to setting the value of the current minimum to +Inf and bubbling it down rather than changing the heap size so that I could reuse the same memory footprint in iterations of A?
I ask because I have an application where an outer routine A calls an inner routine B which modifies an array of values v in each inner iteration by (i) setting the current minimum to +Inf, and (ii) using the value of the minimum (before it was set to +Inf) to identify a few other elements to modify. So I would prefer to maintain a heap-array of initial size n but effectively exclude some indices/artificially/lazily modify the size of the heap rather than dynamically doing so.
Two questions:

does my logic for avoiding dynamic memory changes make sense? Is there an implementation of what I'm describing?
if I know that I want to modify some indices [1,5,10] in the unsorted list of values (in addition to the current argmin), how do I translate this into indices of my heap-array?


Can you give more details about the second paragraph? What will you do with the minimum that you replace with +Inf? How does that help to delete a specific element in the heap? Why do you want to avoid reducing the heap size? A smaller heap size will eventually reduce its height and thereby reduce the number of comparisons/swaps needed for insert/delete operations, so it is actually good to reduce the heap size when you can. What am I missing here?

@trincot: thanks for the question. I modified the statement to try and clarify. Basically, I am worried that shrinking the size of my heap in routine-B will mean that I have to re-allocate again in each iteration of the outer loop of routine-A. So I'd like to store the heap as an array but perhaps use children/parent functions that exclude indices of already pop!'d minima

Typical implementation of a binary heap involves allocating an array that's larger than initially required, and keeping track of how many items are in the heap. That avoids having to re-allocate the array every time you add or remove an item. You still have to re-allocate as the heap grows, but infrequently.
For example, a common way to grow a heap is by doubling. That is, you initially allocate, say, an array to hold 16 items. And you keep track of how many are used by keeping a Count variable. Whenever you add to the heap, you increase Count. Whenever you remove something, you decrease Count. When the heap has to grow beyond 16 items you re-allocate, making the size 32. You don't eliminate the overhead of re-allocations, but you greatly reduce it. And if you know up front that the heap is going to contain, say, 20,000 items, then you can initialize the backing array with that size and there's no need for reallocations at all.
Most implementations I've seen provide no way to reduce the allocated size of the heap. That's typically not a problem, because you can easily allocate a new, smaller, heap and copy the existing one to it. Some implementations have a TrimExcess() method that you can call to free up space if required, but it doesn't really make sense to have the heap automatically shrink if it gets too much free space. Such a feature would interfere with the technique of pre-allocating a large heap.
To change an item in the heap (i.e. modify its value), you make the change in-place and then bubble it up or sift it down, as appropriate. There's no need to delete or insert anything.
To remove an item from the heap, you replace the item to be removed with the last item on the heap, and then bubble up or sift down as appropriate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706363/56778 gives a little more info on that.
